# Classification evaluation: How to sample the confusion matrix for unbalanced data?

Tags: classification, sample-size, unbalanced-classes, confusion-matrix

### Goal and Background

- My goal is to **classify Twitter accounts**: Account of scientist
  0 = no, 1 = yes.
- To this end, a scientist identification algorithm was applied
  to a total of **7 Mio. accounts** (no probabilities for classification, only 0 and 1).
- EDIT: accounts are classified by matching keywords in profile descriptions (e.g. "scientist", "researcher", etc.)
- It resulted in **17.000 classified positives**.
- To evaluate correctness of results, **accounts need to be validated manually** (searching the web for CVs etc.)

### Question

Given this data with very unbalanced classes: **How many accounts from which class need to be validated for creating a confusion matrix** (and calculating precision/recall)**?**

### My approach so far

My approach for building the confusion matrix so far: Random sample of 100 classified positives, and random sample of 100 classified negatives (200 in total, based on sample size calculation for 2x2 Chi² test using [GPower](https://osf.io/zqphw/download)). This resulted in:

|  | classified positives | classified negatives |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **actual positives** | 90 | 0 |
| **actual negatives** | 10 | 100 |

I am mostly interested in precision, i.e., how many of classified positives are actual positives. According to the confusion matrix: Precision = 90 / (90 + 10) = .9

### Does this make sense?

- From what I understand (by background is in psychology), evaluation of the classification algorithm is done using a confusion matrix using a random sample of sufficient size. [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193909/relation-between-precision-recall-and-sample-size) gives some advice regarding sample size.
- However, if I draw a random sample of all 7 Mio. accounts, the chance of having any classified positives in that sample is very low: Only 0.24 % of all accounts were classified positive. That's why I sampled randomly within each class (classified positives vs. classified negatives).
- Does this make sense? The manual validation of accounts is labor intensive and sampling the class of classified negatives 410 times larger (for matching the ratio of 17.000 to (7 Mio. - 17.000) is not feasible.

(EDIT: replaced "predicted" with "classified", as no prediction model was applied but a keyword-based classification)

Comment: If you are having to ignore data to get your estimate, think again.  Your problem is one for estimating tendencies, not doing arbitrary classification.  Use a probability model.   Then you can do the right thing and refuse to classify individuals who are in the uncertain probability interval.  See https://fharrell.com/post/classification

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the helpful blog post, @FrankHarrell. Obviously, I used “prediction” inappropriately here (I edited the post). For clarification: The researcher identification algorithm is basically a **keyword-based decision making** (see EDIT in section "Goal and Background"). Given that this approach does not estimate tendencies and probabilities: is this more a problem of information retrieval rather than classification? And still: For how many accounts do I need to check CVs in order to decide whether this keyword-based classification works for researcher identification?

Comment: Classification is a forced choice, and requires you to arbitrarily put close calls into a category without alerting you to it being a close call.  You can use a probability model for decision making.  If you define a utility/cost/loss function and merge it with the probability you can choose the decision that maximizes expected utility.  WIthout a utility function you can define your own prob. cutoffs for the decisions and define an uncertainty zone for which you would not draw a conclusion.